# dependent dropdown with json data in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angularjs

I am trying to make dependent dropdown using JSON data

Used (for in) to get the key to integrate it in the dropdown but didn't work,whatever i searched every time json data is getting accessed by key to get the value in this structure i am able to get it in dropdown [{name:"india"},{name:"usa"}].But with current json structure i am not able to do it.

**HTML:-**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl3">
 <select>
  <option>Select Country</option>
  <option ng-repeat="country in chooseCountries"></option>
  <option ng-repeat="states in country"></option>
  <option ng-repeat="city in states"></option>
 </select>
</div>
```

**JS:-**

```
app.controller('myCtrl3',function($scope,$http){
 $http({
  url:'js/country.json',
  method:'GET'
 })
 .then(function(response){
 $scope.chooseCountries = response.data;
 });
});
```

**JSON(country.json):-**

```
[{
"INDIA": {
    "KARNATAKA": ["BANGALORE", "UDUPI", "MANGALORE"],
    "TELENGANA": ["HYDERABAD", "GUNTUR", "SHANKERPALLY"]
},
"USA": {
    "CALIFORNIA": ["SAN JOSE", "SAN HOSE", "NEW YORK"],
    "FLORIDA": ["MIAMI", "DENVER"],
    "INDIAPOLIS": ["INDIANA", "MASACHUTTEUS"]
},
"AUSTRALIA": {
    "NEW SOUTH WALES": ["SYDNEY", "BRISBANE"],
    "QUEENSLAND": ["PERTH", "VICTORIA"],
    "WESTERN AUSTRALIA": ["MELBOURNE", "MCG"]
}
}]
```

i want the output first dropdown should show INDIA,USA,AUSTRALIA if i click INDIA second dropdown should show KARNATAKA AND TELENGANA in the third dropdown list if i click KARNATAKA it should show BANGALORE,UDUPI,MANGALORE.Didn't got any error but coudn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you can't alter the format of the returned JSON. If that is the case, you don't have a nicely formed object hierarchy that you can use so instead you'll have to fall back to using `(key, value)`. Below is a simple example of how you can accomplish what you are after.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countryChoices = [{
      "INDIA": {
        "KARNATAKA": ["BANGALORE", "UDUPI", "MANGALORE"],
        "TELENGANA": ["HYDERABAD", "GUNTUR", "SHANKERPALLY"]
      },
      "USA": {
        "CALIFORNIA": ["SAN JOSE", "SAN HOSE", "NEW YORK"],
        "FLORIDA": ["MIAMI", "DENVER"],
        "INDIAPOLIS": ["INDIANA", "MASACHUTTEUS"]
      },
      "AUSTRALIA": {
        "NEW SOUTH WALES": ["SYDNEY", "BRISBANE"],
        "QUEENSLAND": ["PERTH", "VICTORIA"],
        "WESTERN AUSTRALIA": ["MELBOURNE", "MCG"]
      }
    }];
    $scope.selectedCountry = {};
    $scope.selectedState = {};
    $scope.selectedCity = '';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in countryChoices[0]"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="value as key for (key,value) in selectedCountry"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="value as value for value in selectedState"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lex i got it

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work, your json data should be like this:

```
[{
  country: "INDIA",
  states: [
  {
    "KARNATAKA": {
      cities: ["BANGALORE", "UDUPI", "MANGALORE"]
    }
  }
}]
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: in this way i have attained the output i want to do it with current json structure to learn how key is being used in dependent dropdown